# Search Activities => mention not showing up

Tags: google-plus

When I'm calling the API endpoint /activities with a query, some posts are not returned in the API.

This post:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AngelMart%C3%ADnGonz%C3%A1lez/posts/ZiBnnVNtzu8
Did not show up with query="movistar"

What should the query be to fetch this post?

Comment: I gess you use plus.activities.list. Don't see the fiels 'query' in the api. Where did you get that ?

Comment: It's the G+ pages API for partners

Comment: Did you have a link ?

Comment: The documentation is only available for partners, so I can't give you any links to these docs